# IBAction on UISwitch in custom UITableViewCell causes error

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` and a custom `TableViewCell` and within that UITableViewCell there is a UISwitch. This switch is wired to an IBAction, but as soon as i tap the switch, i get an error:

```
 unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x13ce30a50
```

**SelectFriendsViewController.swift**

```
class SelectFriendsViewController: UITableViewController, SelectorDelegate {
    func selectUser(string: String) {
        selectedUser = string;
    }

    .... lots of code removed for simplification.

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:SelectorTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SelectorTableViewCell;

        cell.delegate = self;
    }

}
```

---

```
protocol SelectorDelegate {
    func selectUser(string: String)
}

class SelectorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var swUser: UISwitch! = UISwitch();
    @IBOutlet var lblUserName: UILabel! = UILabel();

    var delegate: SelectorDelegate!

    @IBAction func SwitchUser(sender: UISwitch) {
        //delegate.selectUser("test");
        //even with just this println i get the error
        println("test");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. I suspect it might be a wiring issue between the IBOutlet and IBAction. Can you test by replacing `delegate.selectUser("test")` with a simple `println("test")` statement?

Comment: I replaced it with a println, and that gives me the exact same error. But, as fas as i can see, the IBAction seems to be wired to the switch. That is, if i point to the dot in front of the IBAction, the switch on the storyboard is high lighted.

Comment: I updated my question, so that it now addresses the exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some strange stuff in this code:

1. your cellForRowAtIndexPath should return a cell (you probably have done this, and just didn't copy it across to your stackoverflow question)
2. You're generating your UISwitch either from storyboard or xib as you say 'the switch on the storyboard is highlighted' - however you're also instantiating these in code!
   eg.

   ```
   @IBOutlet var swUser: UISwitch! = UISwitch();
   ```

But I believe your problem in the end is related to your IBAction 'SwitchUser'. You either renamed this method at some point or created an IBAction earlier and then deleted it. To check the current status of your IBActions, click on your cell in the storyboard or xib and open the Connections Inspector. I bet you'll find your problem there.

Comment: Yes, there i found my problem, in the Connections Inspector! I didn't know that that thing existed. Thanks man! There were indeed 3 functions connected, from which obviously only 1 still existed. I guess this indeed came from renaming the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the function name to switchUser instead of SwitchUser

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_243